# Building and Rebuilding deletes worldserver.exe and other files

Tags: azerothcore

So, my problem is essentially that any time I try to install a module, everything breaks. I'm a total laymen, so a lot of this was very alien and difficult for me, but eventually I got a server running from a video guide. All was 100% fine. But when I try to install modules, things go badly. It's not entirely clear to me how to install them, but it seems like I do everything correct. I do the git clone thing into the modules folder, or just download and paste the extracted files into the modules folder. Then I'm told I need to use CMake again and configure until the red goes away, generate, then click the button to open it in Visual Studio. From there I've tried a few things, always to failure. 1. Click Rebuild. 2. Clean and then Rebuild. 3. Build. 4. Clean and then Build. All of those options fail, usually deleting my worldserver.exe and two other, unknown files/folders. Some times worldserver AND authserver.exe get deleted, along with the other, unknown files/folders. If I replace them with backups I've made (because I've tried this so many times) the server works, but the modules don't.

The server works.
I tried installing numerous different modules.
I configure, generate, and open the file(s).
Build, rebuild, clean, etc., all seem to delete critical files, most especially worldserver.exe and authserver.exe, and make the server unusable.
It should not do that?

EDIT:

This is the part of the log that indicates failure and deletes my worldserver.exe without replacing it:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '......\modules\RelWithDebInfo\modules.lib'
> Done building project "worldserver.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
> Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------
> Building Custom Rule C:/AzerothCore/CMakeLists.txt
> Build: 17 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
> Build started at 4:36 PM and took 10:44.841 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you compile new code, worldserver and potentially authserver need to be replaced with the new data. It's mandatory when adding a module.

Check the output of your compiler.
The classic install guide on ACs wiki suggests Visual Studio for that. Does it show errors when it's done compiling?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your time. I'm trying another total reinstall atm, so I can't test this second, but the output does mention something along the lines of worldserver.exe FAIL or something, and it says 3 things failed in total, though I'm not sure what the others are.

It never replaces worldserver.exe or authsever.exe, it just removes them entirely from the folder. Am I selecting the wrong rebuild option? Should I be cleaning? I don't really understand any of it, I'm afraid.

Comment: The compiler failing happens probably due to an outdated or incompatible module. It's impossible to tell what might cause it without seeing the actual error though.